# Converting JSON array to relational data in Oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have the following array within a json file that I need to convert to relational data:

```
"items": [
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3"
  ]
```

I am using the following query for the conversion but not able to display the required values within the array:

```
select items
from test_table stg,
     json_table(stg.json_data, '$.items[*]'
                columns (
                          items path  '$.items'
                        )
               );
```

what am i missing?

Comment: `columns <datatype> path '...'` is resolved relative to the path specified in the table. Use `$` as a column path

Answer (score 0):

You have already descended into the array with the outer path `$.items[*]`. From there the array elements are at the path `$`, not `$.items`.

```sql
SELECT items
FROM   test_table stg
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         stg.json_data,
         '$.items[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           items path  '$'
         )
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (json_data CLOB CHECK (json_data IS JSON));

INSERT INTO test_table(json_data)
  VALUES ('{"items": ["item1","item2","item3"]}');
```

Outputs:

| ITEMS |
| --- |
| item1 |
| item2 |
| item3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ONPBmod2)